# Android proximity alert,from kml file

Tags: java, android

im trying to plan and build a small android app that takes in a kml file of co-ordinates, these coordinates are grouped together as a lineString with maybe a couple of dozen points in each linestring, im trying to build an app that as the user travels if they are within a set of these cordinates marked as a line on the road an alert will be prompted, there may be thousands of these lines within one kml file, I know how to prompt alerts etc. but was wondering if my approach of parsing all these cordinates when the program starts then constantly check if a user is near any of them and if inside the linestring prompt would be a good way to go about it? this way does not seem efficient at all, any ideas would be great before i get started.

ex.
lineString
coordinates
cordinates 1
.......... 2
etc.........
/cordinates
/lineString

maybe thousands of these lines

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I agree that if you're periodically checking a user's location and comparing co-ordinates against a large list then it is going to be inefficient (and cpu intensive).

Firstly I'll be upfront and say I'm just throwing in abstract comments/ideas as nobody else has responded. I've never used KML nor written an app that does anything like you describe so I'm just throwing in abstract comments/ideas.

You don't give any detail about the extent of your LineStrings (for example, will the kml file have LineStrings that stretch a long distance? e.g., The Great Wall of China). You also don't explain how the user is likely to be travelling (walking, cycling, driving etc.).

Based on the above, I would work on creating a subset of total co-ordinates based on the geographic area covered by the kml file, the user's starting location and the mode of transport (i.e., how far they are likely to travel in a given amount of time).

The problem with the above, of course, is that you can't rely on matching longitude or latitude individually so you'd need to subset using actual distance between the user and any points defined for each LineString. To keep it efficient (and keep your subset as small as possible), you'd also need to update your subset as the user moves away from or towards co-ordinates defined in the various LineStrings.

Hmm, abstract indeed and possibly of no help but it was an interesting problem to mull over.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback MisterS, some good ideas, I like the approach of creating a new subset of co-ords that are close by, sorry for not clarifying but the kml line string would not stretch more then a few miles.

Comment: I think each line point is 500m apart, this will be used in a car, so i was thinking creating a subset of locations of a certain mile radius that would update when the user is nearing the furthers point, have a radius of say 50miles, Im still a noob with Android and google maps and need to do a lot more research but i have already created a simple google maps overlay which gives the users current position and will also allow for a proximtiy alert depending on location marked.